# storing AJAX response into variable for use later in script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, response

here is the gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/tconroy/e52e0e7402face8f048e

Basically, my program is broken down into several steps:

1. retrieve user input from N number of inputs (user can add/remove)
2. perform AJAX query on each input, retrieving JSON formatted weather data for each.
3. on successful AJAX, pass the data to `dataReady()` function.
4. `dataReady()` function stores the data into a global `Array[]`

The problem is the AJAX data is **not storing in the global array**. how can I save the JSON response for use later in the program? I need to store all my weather data in one array, so I can iterate through it to create my graph later in the program.

The part causing issues in particular:

```
function getWeatherData(){
  // set up query strings.
  var queryBase  = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=",
      queryEnd   = "&format=json&num_of_days=5&key="+weatherAPIKey;

  // iterate through each address input
  $('.inp').each(function(){
    // setup query
    var inp   = this;
    var addr  = encodeURIComponent( inp.value );
    var query = queryBase + addr + queryEnd;
    // perform query
    $.ajax({
      url: query,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(json){
        // format our response data into object, push it into container array.
        var objName = String(decodeURIComponent(addr));
        var objVals = json.data.weather;
        dataReady(objName, objVals);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert(errMsg);
      }
    });
  }); // end $('.inp').each();
  // setup the graph
  setupGraph();
} // end getWeatherData();


function dataReady(objName, objVals) {
  console.log('dataReady() called.');
  responseValues[objName] = objVals;
}
```

Comment: Generally, it's good to post the part of code giving you troubles. Don't link to Github gists. We like to see your code directly in the question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Particularly what do you mean by "not storing in the global array"? Just store it in a global variable.

Comment: @CameronTinker: I have added the problematic code to the OP.

Comment: When is "laster in the program"? Did you ensure that all the ajax requests have loaded yet when you access the array?

Comment: @freakish: the data is not saving to the global variable...... that is the issue. In the ajax response I say `globalVar.push(responseData)` and it does not save.

Comment: @Prefix Where did you define `responseValues`? Plus I don't see any `.push` call.

Comment: @freakish: at the very top of the script, as a global, outside of any function, `var responseValues = new Array();`

Comment: around the " dataReady(objName, objVals);" part, use something like responseValues[objName]=objVals;  then, you can check the object "responseValues" for the name key before you load the ajax and if cached, call dataReady with the cached info instead of from the ajax callback

Comment: @Prefix In that case the code looks fine (except for horrible `async: false,` setting which does not even work since it is JSONP). Does it enter `dataReady` function? If I understand this correctly you are dealing with an issue of asynchronous calls, i.e. `dataReady` is called after `setupGraph` is called. Am I correct?

Comment: @freakish, yes, if I `console.log(objName, objVals);` in `dataReady()` both the name and values are printed, however when I try and save them to the global array, `responseValues[objName] = objVals;`, `responseValues` remains empty.

Comment: @freakish: now that you mention it I think that's exactly what is happening! `setupGraph` is being called before all the ajax has gone through `dataReady`. what are some good ways to prevent this?

Comment: setupGraph() should be called after dataReady() in the success function, or alternatively from inside the dataReady() function

Comment: @MaKR: the problem is, the AJAX call is a loop, as I need to perform the call for user-defined number of inputs (querying API with each input). I don't want to call `setupGraph()` until each AJAX call is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand (see comments) you are dealing with a typical problem with asynchronous calls. You call AJAX, then you call `setupGraph()` but the ajax response will arrive after that call, because it is asynchronous.

First of all, doing `async: false` is bad, wrong and the source of all evil. Don't use it never ever. In your case it won't even work, because you **can't force JSONP to be synchronous**. But even if you could let me repeat my self, because this is important: **don't ever use `async: false`**.

Now back to your problem. What you should is to use deferred callbacks instead:

```
var reqs = [];
$('.inp').each(function(){
    // some code
    reqs.push(
        $.ajax({
            // some settings
        })
    );
});

$.when.apply($, reqs).then(function() {
    setupGraph();
});
```

Read more about `$.when` here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: That was it! I never even knew about $.when. Thank you!