# How to ensure Ajax has defined object which is used in later external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I ensure an object is set in time using Ajax (i.e. `myObj.myProp`) for some other external script which uses it (i.e. `someFastScriptWhichAccesses_myObj_myProp.js`)?  Note that I have other external files which use the same object, and thus did not wish to place the Ajax in `someFastScriptWhichAccesses_myObj_myProp.js`.

Related Posts:
[storing AJAX response into variable for use later in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525414/storing-ajax-response-into-variable-for-use-later-in-script).  Does not consider an external file uses the object.  Also, is adamant that `async: false` should not be used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var myObj={};
            $.get( "someSlowURL.php", function( data ) {
                myObj.myProp=data;
                }, "json" );
        </script>
        <script src="someFastScriptWhichAccesses_myObj_myProp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  func = function (responce) {
    console.log(responce);
  }
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $.get( "someSlowURL.php", function( data ) {
    func(data);
    }, "json" );
</script>
```

or try to use:

```
$.getScript()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will check this out.  Know if there are any concerns about taking such an approach?